# Haskell/Parsec: how do I use Text.Parsec.Token with Text.Parsec.Indent (from the indents package)

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, indentation, parsec

The *indents* package for Haskell's Parsec provides a way to parse indentation-style languages (like Haskell and Python). It redefines the `Parser` type, so how do you use the token parser functions exported by Parsec's [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) module, which are of the normal `Parser` type?

## Background

- [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec.html) is a parser combinator library, whatever that means.
- [IndentParser 0.2.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IndentParser-0.2.1) is an old package providing the two modules [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.IndentParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/IndentParser/0.2.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-IndentParser.html) and [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.IndentParser.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/IndentParser/0.2.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-IndentParser-Token.html)
- [indents 0.3.3](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents-0.3.3) is a new package providing the single module [`Text.Parsec.Indent`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/indents/0.3.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Indent.html)

Parsec comes with [a load of modules](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec.html). most of them export a bunch of useful parsers (e.g. `newline` from [`Text.Parsec.Char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Char.html#v:newline), which parses a newline) or parser combinators (e.g.  `count n p` from [`Text.Parsec.Combinator`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v:count), which runs the parser *p*, *n* times)

However, the module [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) would like to export functions which are parametrized by the user with features of the language being parsed, so that, for example, the `braces p` function will run the parser *p* after parsing a '{' and before parsing a '}', ignoring things like comments, the syntax of which depends on your language.

The way that [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) achieves this is that it exports a single function [`makeTokenParser`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:makeTokenParser), which you call, giving it the parameters of your specific language (like what a comment looks like) and it returns a record containing all of the functions in [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html), adapted to your language as specified.

Of course, in an indentation-style language, these would need to be adapted further (perhaps? here's where I'm not sure – I'll explain in a moment) so I note that [the (presumably obsolete) IndentParser package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IndentParser-0.2.1) provides a module [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.IndentParser.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/IndentParser/0.2.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-IndentParser-Token.html) which looks to be a drop-in replacement for [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html).

I should mention at some point that all the Parsec parsers are monadic functions, so they do magic things with state so that error messages can say at what line and column in the source file the error appeared

## My Problem

For a couple of small reasons it appears to me that [the indents package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents-0.3.3) is more-or-less the current version of IndentParser, however it does not provide a module that looks like [`Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.IndentParser.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/IndentParser/0.2.1/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-Parsec-IndentParser-Token.html), it only provides `Text.Parsec.Indent`, so **I am wondering how one goes about getting all the token parsers from `Text.Parsec.Token`** (like `reserved "something"` which parses the reserved keyword "something", or like `braces` which I mentioned earlier).

It would appear to me that (the new) `Text.Parsec.Indent` works by some sort of monadic state magic to work out at what column bits of source code are, so that it doesn't need to modify the token parsers like `whiteSpace` from [`Text.Parsec.Token`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.3/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#v:whiteSpace), which is probably why it doesn't provide a replacement module. But I am having a problem with types.

You see, without `Text.Parsec.Indent`, all my parsers are of type `Parser Something` where Something is the return type and `Parser` is a type alias defined in Text.Parsec.String as

```
type Parser = Parsec String ()
```

but with `Text.Parsec.Indent`, instead of importing `Text.Parsec.String`, I use my own definition

```
type Parser a = IndentParser String () a
```

which makes all my parsers of type `IndentParser String () Something`, where IndentParser is defined in Text.Parsec.Indent. but the token parsers that I'm getting from `makeTokenParser` in `Text.Parsec.Token` are of the wrong type.

If this isn't making much sense by now, it's because I'm a bit lost. The type issue is [discussed a bit here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/16/using-text-parsec-indent-to-parse-an-indentation-sensitive-language-with-haskells-parsec-library/).

---

The error I'm getting is that I've tried replacing the one definition of `Parser` above with the other, but then when I try to use one of the token parsers from `Text.Parsec.Token`, I get the compile error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.State
                                Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos'
            with actual type `Data.Functor.Identity.Identity'
Expected type: P.GenTokenParser
                 String
                 ()
                 (Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.State Text.Parsec.Pos.SourcePos)
  Actual type: P.TokenParser ()
```

### Links

- [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec.html)
- [IndentParser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/IndentParser-0.2.1) (old package)
- [indents](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/indents-0.3.3), providing Text.Parsec.Indent (new package)
- [some discussion of Parser types](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/03/16/using-text-parsec-indent-to-parse-an-indentation-sensitive-language-with-haskells-parsec-library/) with example code
- [another example of using Text.Parsec.Indent](http://changaco.net/blog/parse-indented-tree/)

Sadly, neither of the examples above use token parsers like those in Text.Parsec.Token.

Comment: A `Parser Something` is a `ParsecT String () Identity Something`. The wrapped monad is `Identity`. But an `IndentParser` wraps `State SourcePos`. The things you get from a `TokenParser` are all `ParsecT s u m Something`, so perhaps it's as easy as generalising your types to `ParsecT String () m Something` from `Parser Something`. Then they can be used with `m = Identity` or `m = State SourcePos`, as needed.

Comment: I'm trying something like that, and getting `Not in scope: type variable 'm'`. So I try adding the context `Monad m =>`, and I get `Illegal polymorphic or qualified type: forall (m :: * -> *). Monad m => ParsecT s u m`

Comment: Can you give an example of such a signature?

Comment: I tried replacing the line `type Parser a = IndentParser String () a` with `type Beetle s u = (Monad m) => ParsecT s u m` followed by `type Parser = Beetle String ()` or `type Beetle s u a = ParsecT s u m a` and `type Parser a = Beetle String () a`. All my parser functions are still declared as things like `foo :: Parser Something`.

Comment: Ah, no, you must mention the `m` in the type signature of your parsers. `type Beetle m = ParsecT String () m`, and then let your parsers have type `Beetle m Something`.

Comment: But how do I create indentation-aware token parsers, or indentation-aware parsers that use token parsers? I surely have to declare parsers imported from Text.Token.Parser as `Beetle Identity Something`, but then doesn't that mean I can't use those in a parser of type `Beetle (State SourcePos) Something`? Would you like to join the [#haskell IRC channel on Freenode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IRC_channel)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25897/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-beetle-952580)

Comment: The chat is now complete, the problem is solved, and I will write up an answer for stackoverflow tomorrow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## What are you trying to do?

It sounds like you want to have your parsers defined everywhere as being of type

`Parser Something`

(where *Something* is the return type) and to make this work by hiding and redefining the `Parser` type which is normally imported from `Text.Parsec.String` or similar. You still need to import some of `Text.Parsec.String`, to make Stream an instance of a monad; do this with the line:

```
import Text.Parsec.String ()
```

Your definition of `Parser` is correct. Alternatively and equivalently (for those following the chat in the comments) you can use

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Text.Parsec.Pos (SourcePos)

type Parser = ParsecT String () (State SourcePos)
```

and possibly do away with the `import Text.Parsec.Indent (IndentParser)` in the file in which this definition appears.

## Error, error on the wall

Your problem is that you're looking at the wrong part of the compiler error message. You're focusing on

```
Couldn't match expected type `State SourcePos' with actual type `Identity'
```

when you should be focusing on

```
Expected type: P.GenTokenParser ...
  Actual type: P.TokenParser ...
```

## It compiles!

Where you "import" parsers from `Text.Parsec.Token`, what you actually do, of course (as you briefly mentioned) is first to define a record your language parameters and then to pass this to the function `makeTokenParser`, which returns a record containing the token parsers.

You must therefore have some lines that look something like this:

```
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P

beetleDef :: P.LanguageDef st
beetleDef =
    haskellStyle {
        parameters, parameters etc.
        }

lexer :: P.TokenParser ()
lexer = P.makeTokenParser beetleDef
```

... but a `P.LanguageDef st` is just a `GenLanguageDef String st Identity`, and a `P.TokenParser ()` is really a `GenTokenParser String () Identity`.

You must change your type declarations to the following:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Text.Parsec.Pos (SourcePos)
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P

beetleDef :: P.GenLanguageDef String st (State SourcePos)
beetleDef =
    haskellStyle {
        parameters, parameters etc.
        }

lexer :: P.GenTokenParser String () (State SourcePos)
lexer = P.makeTokenParser beetleDef
```

... and that's it! This will allow your "imported" token parsers to have type `ParsecT String () (State SourcePos) Something`, instead of `Parsec String () Something` (which is an alias for `ParsecT String () Identity Something`) and your code should now compile.

(For maximum generality, I'm assuming that you might be defining the `Parser` type in a file separate from, and imported by, the file in which you define your actual parser functions. Hence the two repeated `import` statements.)

## Thanks

Many thanks to [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) for helping me with this.

Comment: It appears that `st` and `()` are interchangeable, and everything seems to behave exactly the same with any combination. I suspect that this is the slot for "user state", which is `()` for me because I don't need extra state for anything. If I try to define my `Parser` with `type Parser = ParsecT String st (State SourcePos)` it complains about an unknown type variable 'st', but otherwise it seems that I can use either `st` or `()` anywhere in these definitions.

Comment: Note that if you leave `haskellStyle` in front of the `LanguageDef` record it can cause problems (due to the required import of `Parsec.Language`, and associated type signatures).

If you're willing to spend some extra keystrokes, you can actually fill out the entire `Parsec.Token.LanguageDef` record manually, which lets you to avoid importing the `Parsec.Language` module.

Comment: I'm actually using emptyDef rather than haskellStyle. Would I still benefit from filling out the entire record?